# htmlentities is making string empty

Tags: php, html-entities

I am running this chunk of code:

```
var_dump($this->string);
$this->string = htmlentities($this->string, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8", false);
var_dump($this->string);
```

And it is outputting the string in the first `var_dump()`, but it is empty in the second `var_dump()`. Why is it doing this?

```
string(1787) "##Welcome newcomer

We have a `great place` here for you to write whatever you wish, and share it with your friends, family and other random people. Hopefully you enjoy writing for us, we can't wait to see what you have to write about and share with the community! 

##Markdown

We don't use your average editor, we use a much simpler one to write fast HTML code. It is called **Markdown**. Here we will show some basic and common Markdown syntax.

|||OTABLE|||
|||OTR|||
|||OTH|||Example|||CTH|||
|||OTH|||Syntax|||CTH|||
|||OTH|||Description|||CTH|||
|||CTR|||
|||OTR|||
|||OTD|||**Bold**|||CTD|||
|||OTD||||||AST||||||AST|||Bold|||AST||||||AST|||  
|||UND||||||UND|||Bold|||UND||||||UND||||||CTD|||
|||OTD|||Makes text thicker.|||CTD|||
|||CTR|||
|||OTR|||
|||OTD|||_Italic_|||CTD|||
|||OTD||||||AST|||Italic|||AST|||  
|||UND|||Italic|||UND||||||CTD|||
|||OTD|||Makes text slanted|||CTD|||
|||CTR|||
|||OTR|||
|||OTD|||[Google](http://google.com)|||CTD|||
|||OTD||||||LBR|||Google|||RBR||||||LPR|||http://google.com) |||CTD|||
|||OTD|||Makes a text link to a webpage|||CTD|||
|||CTR|||
|||OTR|||
|||OTD|||
|||OBLQU|||I am  
part of  
a quote  
|||CBLQU||||||CTD|||
|||OTD|||
|||GTR|||I am  
|||GTR|||part of  
|||GTR|||a quote  
|||CTD|||
|||OTD|||Creates a quote area|||CTD|||
|||CTR|||
|||OTR|||
|||OTD|||
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>I Am The Title</title>
        </head>
    </html>
|||CTD|||
|||OTD|||
    <html>|||BR|||
        <head>|||BR|||
            <title>I Am The Title</title>|||BR|||
        </head>|||BR|||
    </html>
|||CTD|||
|||OTD|||Creates a block of code|||CTD|||
|||CTR|||
|||OTR|||
|||OTD|||I am `inline code`|||CTD|||
|||OTD|||I am |||TIK|||inline code|||TIK||||||CTD|||
|||OTD|||Creates an inline code block|||CTD|||
|||CTR|||
|||CTABLE|||"
string(0) ""
```

Comment: The `htmlentities()` docs say "*If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given encoding an empty string will be returned*". Having said that, I tried your code and got the proper output...

Comment: I don't think so, because it is strange, I am running this on a test page and it works fine, but when I run it within my actual web page it doesn't work...

Comment: Adding `ENT_IGNORE` does fix the issue though

Comment: what is the PHP version? Using `ENT_IGNORE` flag is discouraged as it  [may have security implications](http://unicode.org/reports/tr36/#Deletion_of_Noncharacters). If `ENT_IGNORE` works, it proves that your contents have invalid characters.

Comment: Also, `ENT_DISALLOWED` flag will replace the invalid characters by `U+FFFD` in your case ( UTF-8 ), thus you can locate where your invalid characters are.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Is so, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `"UTF-8"` to `"iso-8859-1"` in the third parameter. This is a well know bu… [feature introduced in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.other.php). I suppose it does the job.

*God damn PHP and its developers.*

Answer (score -2):

```
htmlentities(string, quotestyle, character-set)
```

Only three parameters

Comment: Nope. It accepts up to 4 - have a look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).